# How to change the value of max_connections variable?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

How i can change the variable max_connection to a higher value than 214.
I try this on my.cnf but doesn't work

```
max_connections = 2000
```

The version of MySql is 5.6.24 and i already restarted the server.

Answer (score 1):

You should also configure the open_files_limit and the table_open_cache , but be careful with open_files_limit_value not exceed the OS maximum.

1. Get mysql PID
2. list the max open file for my sql using

> cat /proc/ *PID* /limits | grep "open files"

3. In /etc/my.cnf configure the following

   open_files_limit= 4096 #the maximum of the OS

   max_connections = 500

   table_open_cache = 600

restart mysql server using

> `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

You can increase this value in main config file (e.g., /etc/my.cnf) using this syntax:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=250
```

If it not work 
then either execute `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 250;` in MySQL and restart MySQL.

**NOTE:**

> You can find this error if your scripts open persistent connections, wich aren't closed even if the script terminates. Use mysql_connect() instead of mysql_pconnect() unless you have a good reason. In particular, check this setting in third-party scripts (such as osCommerce).

Server administrators can disable persistent connections for PHP scripts in php.ini file:

```
[MySQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mysql.allow_persistent=Off
```

Scripts won't fail, they'll just use non-persistent connections silently.

Comment: dude this command is already deprecated and doesn't work on 5.6.24